# Bootstrap DateTime Piker does not work in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get the bootstrap datetime picker from here:

```
http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php
```

I did exactly the same but the datepicker didnt show up.

here are my code in cakephp:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min', FALSE);?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-datetimepicker.min',FALSE);?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap-datetimepicker'); ?>
<div class="controls input-append date" id="dp">
                <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script>    
$('#dp').datetimepicker({
    language:  'en',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to move your script to a dom ready handler

Comment: @ArunPJohny do you mean to put the code inside $(document).ready(function ()           {

});

if yes, it doesnt work too.

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zkgeC/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh. But why did it not work in my case? I guess the import of libraries is wrong.

Comment: that is one possibility... check the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh, it turns out that 2 libraries are unable to be loaded.

Comment: Show it working with just HTML/JS, then show your replication attempt and how it's generated code differs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries are not loading because you did not call include method of Cakephp

Add this after `<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap-datetimepicker'); ?>`

```
echo $this->fetch('css'); 
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

2nd wrap javascript in ready handler, Try this.

```
<script>
      $(function() {
         $('#dp').datetimepicker({
    language:  'en',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
        });



</script>
```